# matplotlib scale text (curly brackets)

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I would like to use curly brackets '}' in my plot all having different heights, but the same width.
So far when scaling the text, the width scales proportionally:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
ax.text(0.2, 0.2, '}', fontsize=20)
ax.text(0.4, 0.2, '}', fontsize=40)
plt.show()
```

The only idea that comes to my mind is overlaying images of braces with the matplotlib image, e.g. using `svgutils` like in [Importing an svg file a matplotlib figure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452451/importing-an-svg-file-a-matplotlib-figure), but this is cumbersome.

A solution with vector graphics as output would be ideal.

Comment: I did think that using `LaTeX` text rendering, and a `\scalebox` would do the job here, but it appears that [doesn't work](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/7480).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To get a letter in scaled only in one dimension, e.g. height but keeping the other dimension constant, you may create the curly bracket as `TextPath`. This can be provided as input for a `PathPatch`. And the `PathPatch` may be scaled arbitrarily using `matplotlib.transforms`.

```
import matplotlib.transforms as mtrans
from matplotlib.text import TextPath
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

def curly(x,y, scale, ax=None):
    if not ax: ax=plt.gca()
    tp = TextPath((0, 0), "}", size=1)
    trans = mtrans.Affine2D().scale(1, scale) + \
        mtrans.Affine2D().translate(x,y) + ax.transData
    pp = PathPatch(tp, lw=0, fc="k", transform=trans)
    ax.add_artist(pp)

X = [0,1,2,3,4]
Y = [1,1,2,2,3]
S = [1,2,3,4,1]

for x,y,s in zip(X,Y,S):
    curly(x,y,s, ax=ax)

ax.axis([0,5,0,7])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is it possible to adapt this function to plot a bracket outside of the figure? For instance, to the right?

Comment: @jonboy Sure, you would just need to set the `clip_path` off.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks @ImportanceOfBeingErnest

Comment: Just in case somebody stumbles on this today, as I did, there is a really nice package by Dr. Gao, SiYu published after this question was answered.
It is way more modular than reshaping a string of text, see the examples in the documentations / repo.  https://github.com/iruletheworld/matplotlib-curly-brace
documentation : https://matplotlib-curly-brace.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

I hope it helps others as it did for me!