# Is there a way to iterate over a pattern to repeat it clockwise with matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-lab, bezier, replicate

I was plotting a car using `matplotlib` on `JupyterLab`, a Python distribution offered by Anaconda. I was using ***Bézier curves*** to do so.
When I was about to plot the wheels of the car, I realized that it was going to be extremely slow and stressful to get every single point of those many lines and shapes we have inside the `Y` wheel pattern and plot it. Take a look at it:
[image]

So I wanted to know if there was a way to build one shape `(a list of points)` and iterate over it 360º to repeat the sequence around a central point and make the wheel. My intention is to think as if the shape was the cookie cutter and then I just have to do more cookies using the cutter.

Comment: Yes, it is possible, please post an [mvce](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to guess what your example is.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Yes, it is cumbersome.  The way to go would be to use a vector drawing software, e.g. [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).  You can also create an SVG file in Inkscape and then [import it into matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452451/importing-an-svg-file-into-a-matplotlib-figure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time, I realized that the answer for my question was here in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372480/rotate-point-about-another-point-in-degrees-python/34374437) other question. The function `rotate` provided by Mark Dickinson is all I needed. This function rotates a given point, so all I had to do was to apply this function to all the points inside the PATH list of points. Here is how I did it:

```
def replica(center_of_rotation, times, points, codes, linewidth = 1, c = "black"):
    l = []
    angle = 0
    counter = 1
    while angle <= 360:
        for i in points: 
            l.append(rotate(center_of_rotation, i, math.radians(angle)))
            counter += 1
            if len(l) == len(points):
                ax.add_patch(patches.PathPatch(Path(l, codes), fc="none", transform=ax.transData, color=c, lw = linewidth))
                angle += 360/times
                l = []
            if angle >= 360:
                return
```

The result was awesome, I can replicate any PATH pattern 'N' number of times. I used this to build the wheels of my Lamborghini.

- #### Pattern replicated 1 time:

[image]

- #### Replicated 5 times, just how much I need:

[image]