# Import .svg image and add title and label the x-y axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

I have an image in the .svg format. How do I import it to python and add title and label the axes?

I tried the following:

```
img = plt.imread('./tune.svg')
```

But it throws an error. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: read it as an XML file e.g. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to read it as an XML file and manipulate its DOM tree. You could either use [`xml.dom`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html) or [`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). There are also third-party libraries such as [`lxml`](https://lxml.de).

---

Following an example that uses a [SVG file](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Kantone_der_Schweiz.svg) from Wikipedia (file version of July 26, 2016) showing the Cantons of Switzerland and changes the background colour of the canton of Zurich leverage `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

(The `path` representing the canton of Zurich has an attribute `id` with the value `path2536`.)

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


OUTPUT_FILE = r"C:\Temp\Switzerland.svg"

# read SVG file
with open("Kantone_der_Schweiz.svg", "r") as file:

    # parse DOM
    svg = ET.parse(file)

    # find Path element of Canton of Zurich (ID: path2536)
    canton_zurich = svg.find(".//*[@id='path2536']")

    # replace style value
    canton_zurich.set("style", "fill:#12e9a1")

    # save updated SVG to file
    with open(OUTPUT_FILE, "wb") as output_file:
        svg.write(output_file, encoding="UTF-8")
```

Here some useful links:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG
- https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/python-xml-elementtree
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath
- https://devhints.io/xpath

---

Below another modified example that does not require downloading the SVG file manually and the modified SVG is plotted with [`matplotlib`](https://matplotlib.org/) (since your question is tagged with `matplotlib`).

This example requires the following third-party libraries: 
[`cairosvg`](https://cairosvg.org/), `matplotlib`, and [`PIL`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

```py
import io
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

import cairosvg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image


SVG_URL = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/8b/" \
          "Kantone_der_Schweiz.svg"

request = Request(SVG_URL)

with urlopen(request) as response:

    # read and parse SVG file from URL
    svg = ET.parse(io.BytesIO(response.read()))

    canton_zurich = svg.find(".//*[@id='path2536']")

    canton_zurich.set("style", "fill:#12e9a1")

    # get SVG as a string
    svg_string = ET.tostring(svg.getroot())

    # plot with matplotlib
    # see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/70007704/42659
    png = cairosvg.svg2png(svg_string)
    image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(png))
    plt.imshow(image)
```