# How to insert a SVG into a figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg, subplot, figure

How do I read a subplot from an svg file and insert into a figure as shown in the screenshot below?

**MWE:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from svglib.svglib import svg2rlg

# SVG file
svg_filepath = "Y:/file.svg"

def plot_all(title, method_1_centerx0, method_2_centery0, method_1_centery0, method_2_centerx0, method_1_sigma, method_2_sigma, method_1_r2, method_2_r2, Result_image_path):    
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(3, 2, figsize=(12, 18), gridspec_kw={'hspace': 0.6, 'wspace': 0.4})

    # Increase label and title font size
    label_font_size = 26

    # Plot 1
    ax1 = axes[0, 0]
    ax1.scatter(method_2_centerx0, method_1_centery0)
    ax1.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax1.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax1.text(-0.3, 1.2, '(a)', transform=ax1.transAxes, fontsize=24, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left')

    # Plot 2
    ax2 = axes[0, 1]
    ax2.scatter(method_2_centery0, method_1_centerx0)
    ax2.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax2.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax2.text(-0.3, 1.2, '(b)', transform=ax2.transAxes, fontsize=24, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left')

    # Plot 3
    ax3 = axes[1, 0]
    ax3.scatter(method_2_sigma, method_1_sigma)
    ax3.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax3.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax3.text(-0.3, 1.2, '(c)', transform=ax3.transAxes, fontsize=24, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left')

    # Plot 4
    ax4 = axes[1, 1]
    ax4.scatter(method_2_r2, method_1_r2)
    ax4.set_xlabel('x', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax4.set_ylabel('y', fontsize=label_font_size)
    ax4.text(-0.3, 1.2, '(d)', transform=ax4.transAxes, fontsize=24, verticalalignment='top', horizontalalignment='left')

    # Load and plot the 5th SVG
    ax5 = axes[2, 0]
    drawing5 = svg2rlg(svg_filepath)
    ax5.add_artist(drawing5)

    # Load and plot the 6th SVG
    ax6 = axes[2, 1]
    drawing6 = svg2rlg(svg_filepath)
    ax6.add_artist(drawing6)

    # Set the title for the entire figure
    plt.suptitle(title, fontsize=24)

    # Remove legends
    for ax in axes.flatten():
        ax.legend().set_visible(False)

    # Save the figure to the specified path with no white space
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.savefig(Result_image_path)

    # Show the figure (optional)
    plt.show()
    


plot_all('', np.random.randint(100, size=(5)), np.random.randint(100, size=(5))
        , np.random.randint(100, size=(5)), np.random.randint(100, size=(5))
        , np.random.randint(100, size=(5)), np.random.randint(100, size=(5))
        , np.random.randint(100, size=(5)), np.random.randint(100, size=(5))
        , Result_image_path="D:/All.svg")
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using svgutils as in the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31452451/importing-an-svg-file-into-a-matplotlib-figure) ?