# Add svg image to a subplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, svg

So here is the simple code that is producing a subplot with dark background:-

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6,6), facecolor='black')
ax.set_facecolor('black')
```

And I want [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W6z3mzLFny7FZATOD6TjBilBvdg11BcW/view?usp=sharing) image which is in `.svg` format to be added to the subplot. While using PIL's `Image.open()` and `plt.imread` I am getting `UnidentifiedImageError`. What should I do to read in the `.svg` file and add it to the subplot.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think that is possible right now, save converting the svg to a raster image before plotting

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12161559/plot-svg-within-matplotlib-figure-embedded-in-wxpython) is helpful?